# Ho work locally with <httpCookies requireSSL="true" /> on?

Tags: asp.net, cookies

So, if I set my my web.config to:

```
<httpCookies requireSSL="true" />
```

.. I can't run the application locally. How can I bypass this?

I have tried global.asax instead:

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Secure Session cookie
    if (Request.IsSecureConnection)
    {
        Response.Cookies["ASP.NET_SessionId"].Secure = true;
    }
}
```

.. but this does not seem to work (Inpector shows the cookie as unsecure).

Ideas?

Comment: What is your dev environment? You [can use https during dev with VS/IIS Express easily](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/working-with-ssl-in-web-api)

Comment: Yeah, ended up doing just that :)

Answer (score 0):

Ended up switching to a local SSL dev environment, using the steps in this post:

https://dotnetcodr.com/2015/09/18/how-to-enable-ssl-for-a-net-project-in-visual-studio/